# How to load CUB-200-2011 dataset in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, torch, torchvision, image-classification

I am trying to do fine-grained image classification for CUB-200-2011 dataset, couldn't figure out the correct way for loading the data. I'm using pre-trained ImageNet ResNet-101 for training by freezing all layers except last two layers. Suggest a way to for data loading in Pytorch.

Comment: what about https://github.com/TDeVries/cub2011_dataset/blob/master/cub2011.py? Does it help? If it doesn't, what is the issue you're facing? Do you already have some code to show?

Comment: @kmario23, In the repo u sent, what exactly  does 
 "tgz_md5 = '97eceeb196236b17998738112f37df78' "
mean ?

Comment: That's just the md5 sum of the dataset. [MD5sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum) is to make sure that the data is not corrupted while downloading. Once properly downloaded, the md5sum should match whatever you quoted. In *nix systems, `md5sum` can be accessed from the terminal. For torchvision it's optional tho', please see `download_url()` function in [torchvision.datasets.utils](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/utils.py).